# openai_ros on Ubuntu Focal + ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just would like to have a quick check, is it possible to use openai_ros with ubuntu focal + ros noetic?
the reason I am asking this is I get the following error while trying the last step of the instruction mentioned at here (https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros/src/kinetic-devel/).

> kinwah@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install
> openai_ros
>
> ERROR: the following packages/stacks
> could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved to system dependencies:
>
> openai_ros: No definition of
> [python-catkin-pkg] for OS version
> [focal]

If it is not possible, anyone knows how to resolve this or how can I approach the maintainers for possible workarounds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366833/openai_ros-on-ubuntu-focal-+-ros-noetic/) by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I have gotten in touch with the maintainer team of openai_ros!
According to the email reply, there will be support for Noetic at the beginning of next year. Also for ROS2.

---

Originally posted by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) with karma: 91 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bax](https://answers.ros.org/users/68295/bax/) on 2021-01-20**:
Still having this issue, has there been any news?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I could solve the issue by changing a line in "your_ws/src/openai_ros/openai_ros/package.xml."

I guess that you can find the code `<build_depend>python-catkin-pkg</build_depend>` on line 14 or around it. Although Noetic works on Python3 basically, this code declares catkin-pkg for python2. So, I changed the code to `<build_depend>python3-catkin-pkg</build_depend>` or  `<build_depend>python3-catkin-pkg-modules</build_depend>`. Sorry for the vagueness since it has been a while since I dealt with it. But, either, or both, of them worked well for me. I hope it is also the case for you.

---

Originally posted by [Barikata1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/70043/barikata1984/) with karma: 21 on 2021-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vishal1711](https://answers.ros.org/users/109603/vishal1711/) on 2022-06-30**:
Thanks, after this I am able to run `rosdep install openai_ros`

**Comment by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on 2022-07-07**:
Great job, works perfect for me!